# Space error in perl

Tags: linux, perl

I have written this code:

```
my $dizin = "/home/$kullaniciadi/public_html/dosya.txt";
print $dizin;
```

This result comes:

```
/home/neguzel
/public_html
```

But I want it to be `/home/username/public_html`. I don't want it to be

```
/home/usernames
/public_html
```

How can I remove that line break?

Comment: Where does your `$kullaniciadi` come from? Is it user input? Also, that program cannot give the result you are claiming. The `/meme.txt` part of the string is missing. Please [edit] your question and show your **real** code.

Comment: @simbabque Firstly Thank you for edited. my $kullaniciadi = <STDIN>;

Comment: And, of course, using Turkish variable names makes it ambiguous whether you are referring to the English word "[meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme)" or something else, which, especially when combined with "ne güzel" may not be approriate on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input. It has a line break. `chomp` will remove that newline character `\n` for you.

```
my $kullaniciadi = <STDIN>;
chomp $kullaniciadi;

my $dizin = "/home/$kullaniciadi/public_html/meme.txt";
print $dizin;
```